# What is the best way to share an Excel macro across multiple machines?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

All computers are running Office 2007.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an addin for it, distribute it to all the machines (or work off of a networked copy), then have each user add the addin.